# Database created with doctrine, not shown in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I am following the tutorial for Doctrine: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html

I changed the bootstrap file to include my database to:

```
<?php
// bootstrap.php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

// Create a simple "default" Doctrine ORM configuration for Annotations
$isDevMode = false;
$paths = array(__DIR__."/src");
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
// or if you prefer yaml or XML
//$config = Setup::createXMLMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/config/xml"), $isDevMode);
//$config = Setup::createYAMLMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/config/yaml"), $isDevMode);

// database configuration parameters
$conn = array(
    'host' => '*********',
      'port' => '3306',
      'user' => '********',
      'password' => '****',
      'dbname' => 'bugs',
      'charset' => 'UTF8',
    'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
    'path' => __DIR__ . '/db.sqlite',
);

// obtaining the entity manager
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

Then, I did the rest and create the tables, etc using the following commnad:

```
vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

Later, I logged to my 'myphpadmin' and the database was not there.
Am I missing any step? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are using the driver `pdo_sqlite`. It is creating an SQLite database and not a MySQL database. It should have created the file `db.sqlite`.

Change it to `pdo_mysql` to get the database to show up in phpmyadmin.

Comment: yes, later I figure that and tried to run it again, and now I get:
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                                
  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddr  
  esses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Comment: @inespelaez This is a different question from what you have asked originally. If you have a follow-up question, then pls ask it in its own question.

Comment: You probably did not create the DB. Doctrine will only set up the tables. You'll have to create the actual DB and users yourself.